# Firefox css confusion

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm styling a page in chrome and when i test in firefox, the style is a little different from what I intended, so I searched around and hoping for a solution.  I found `@-moz-document url-prefix()`.  So I copy the exact same code I have from my main.css into my header:

```
<style type="text/css/>
    @-moz-document url-prefix(){
       #nav ul li a.active {
       color: #000000;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       margin-top: 0px;
       border-top: 2px solid rgba(38,38,38,0.8); 
       border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(38,38,38,0.8);
       border-right: 2px solid rgba(38,38,38,0.8);} }
</style>
```

It worked.  But I have not change anything.  I tried to remove it and let firefox run the styling with `main.css`, it went back to not working.  Anyone have anyidea why.  Keep in mind I did not change anything in both my main.css and the `@-moz-document url-prefix()`.  I just simply copy that block of code from my main.css.  Does `@-moz-document url-prefix()` have any special property?

Comment: Not sure to understand. You had this code (without `@-moz...`) in your `main.css`, and you simply have duplicated the code, putting it in this `@-moz-document url-prefix(){ }` wrapper?

Comment: Yes. Basically a duplicate